# Question on switching domains and how to trigger search engines to reindex for an Rails app

Tags: seo, ruby-on-rails

For an app I recently switched domains. I deleted the links between the old domain and heroku and then added a new link between the new domain and heroku, but I didn't put any redirects.

After the change, I only see my old domain (which I deleted) and not my new domain when typing the name of the app.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is something I can do in my app, to let search engines reset my domain to my new app.

In case its helpful, the only SEO I did was:

- setting meta tags
- customisation of 404 and 500 pages
- title tag

Comment: Your question lacks details. How did you "switch" domains? Did you delete the old one? Added a redirection to the new one? Kept it but removed all content? Etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, thanks for your response. I deleted the links between the old domain and heroku and then added a new link between the new domain and heroku. No redirects.

Comment: (update your question with any extra detail or clarification, do not put things in comments)

Comment: Ok added. Thanks for the heads up.